# What is the generalization of the theorem $dim(_1+_2)=dim(_1)+dim(_2)−dim(_1\cap_2)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am considering all $W_i$ to be subspaces of a finite demension vector space say $V$.

How can we generalize this well know theorem to more subspaces?

$dim(_1+_2+...+_n)=dim(_1)+dim(_2)+...+dim(_n)−dim(_1\cap_2\cap...\cap_n)$?

or

$dim(_1+_2+...+_n)=dim(_1)+dim(_2)+...+dim(_n)−dim(\bigcup_{i=1}^n (W_i\cap\sum_{j\neq i}W_j))$?

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17740/is-there-a-version-of-inclusion-exclusion-for-vector-spaces

Comment: See also this highly rated false belief about these dimensions: https://mathoverflow.net/a/23501/5091